# How to Display Unique Content Based on Geolocation Within Same City

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, geolocation, dotnetnuke

For a service provider that runs business at a city we want to target different areas of city using unique phone numbers. We want to display phone number that is best match to visitor's location.

I saw some PHP tutorials for this but we are using DotNetNuke (ASP.NET CMS). Could you guys tell me a solution works for ASP.NET based websites?

I can include some Javascript/JQuery codes if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solution should be server-side independent, no matter do you use .NET, PHP or Rails. You can find some geolocational IP API, for example [this](http://www.ip2location.com/).